# LSXLC ODBC Stored Procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, odbc, lotus-domino, connector, oracle-rdb

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle RDB database using LSXLC (ODBC Connector).
But when it comes to stored procedures I'm having a hard time getting it to work.
The code below always results in "Error: Parameter name not supplied: fnl_date, Connector 'odbc2', Method -Call-". The error is triggered on "count = connection.Call(input, 1, result)"
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
Public Function testLsxlcProc()
    On Error GoTo handleError

    Dim connection As LCConnection("odbc2")
    connection.Server = "source"                                
    connection.Userid = "userid"                                      
    connection.Password = "password"
    connection.procedure = "proc_name"
    connection.Connect

    If connection.IsConnected Then
        Dim input As New LCFieldList()
        Dim result As New LCFieldList()

        Dim break As LCField
        Set break = input.Append("fnl_date", LCTYPE_TEXT)
        break.Text = "2014-07-01"
        Dim agrNo As LCField
        Set agrNo = input.Append("fnl_agreement_no", LCTYPE_TEXT)
        agrNo.Text = "123456"
        Dim curr As LCField
        Set curr = input.Append("fnl_currency_code", LCTYPE_TEXT)
        curr.Text = "SEK"
        Dim stock As LCField
        Set stock = input.Append("fnl_stock_id", LCTYPE_TEXT)
        stock.Text = "01"

        connection.Fieldnames = "status, value"
        Dim count As Integer
        count = connection.Call(input, 1, result)
        Call logger.debug("Count: " & count)
    Else
        Error 2000, "Unable to connect to database."
    End If

handleExit:
    connection.Disconnect
Exit Function
handleError:
    On Error Resume Next
    Call logger.error(Nothing)
    Resume handleExit
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made a stupid mistake and had a mismatch between the name of the input parameter in Domino and the name of the input parameter in the stored procedure.
Make sure all names match up and there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stored-Procedure "mylib.MyStoredProc" wird aufgerufen ...
LcSession.Status = 12325: LC-Error: errCallStoredProc 12325 (Error: Parameter name not supplied: P_S651_AC,  Connector 'odbc2',  Method -Call-)

Solution: changed "mylib" into "MYLIB" and all was well.

Check not only Parameter-Names, but also the Search-Path.